# To use "don't" and "no" in one sentence to make it negative

Tags: multiple-negation

In the intro of [TMNT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A43hbbVNps4) the song goes like this:

> When the evil Shredder attacks, these Turtle boys **don't cut him no slack!**

As what I have searched ["cut someone some slack"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/give%2Fcut%20%28someone%29%20some%20slack) means: *to treat (someone) in a less harsh or critical way*

Based on what I have learned, we either use "don't/doesn't" or "no" for making a sentence negative, like "I don't like it" or "This is no good". If I wanted to make the above idiom negative I would either say:

> these Turtle boys don't cut him any slack!

or

> these Turtle boys cut him no slack!

but why are both of "don't" and "no" used here? If it's OK to use both **don't** and **no** in one sentence in which situations we can do so?

Comment: Using "don't" and "no" in one sentence... don't make no sense.

Comment: @41686d6564 Does is make any sense now?

Comment: That was a joke :) "don't make no sense" has two grammatical errors but it's common usage in informal speech in some dialects as explained in the answer below. To be grammatically correct, I should've said "**doesn't** make **any** sense" or "makes no sense".

Comment: Idioms don't follow the rules.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's an example of a double negative, used in some dialects/regional varieties of English. It's non-standard. It basically means the same as "don't cut him any slack".

Songs often use dialects/regional varieties of English. You may also find these used in literature, for example when directly quoting speech, or possibly even in poetry, rap, movies, etc.

Some examples of double negatives in lines from other songs:

- Ain't no sunshine when she's gone - *Ain't No Sunshine, by Bill Withers*
- I can't get no satisfaction - *Satisfaction, by the Rolling Stones*
- We don't need no education - *Another Brick in the Wall, Part 2, by Pink Floyd*
- It wouldn't be nothing, nothing without a woman or a girl - *It's a Man's World, by James Brown*

Comment: Another well-known exemple is "I didn't do nothing wrong".

Comment: I'd say double negatives themselves are fairly standard (though the word choice might be regional). "[The argument against double negatives is founded on the basis that negation is an absolute concept; something is either present or absent, and adding a second negative to a sentence does not make it more negative than it was before. Nevertheless, the use of double negatives in a cumulative fashion, imposed for a kind of emphasis, exists as far back as Chaucer in the Middle Ages. Shakespeare used it as well](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/double-negative-not-adjective-litotes)"

Comment: @anotherdave I'm not "arguing against" the use of double negatives here.

Comment: @BillyKerr Sorry probably quoted too much of that blog post by Merriam Webster! I generally agree with your answer, just disagreeing that they're non-standard since they're in common use dating back to Chaucer/Shakespeare.

Comment: @anotherdave I mean non-standard in regard to formal English grammar.   Non-standard does not mean they are not common or widely understood. English language learners are generally taught formal English grammar, so when they see something like this, it confuses the hell out of them, as it goes against everything they've been taught.

Comment: @BillyKerr sure, I understood alright. But another example (from the blog) is stuff like "_But, as the Economist editorial also noted, it’s not unheard of for U.S. Presidents to talk in glowing terms about their Chinese counterparts._ - [New Yorker]", which to me would read quite formally & as standard English. So was just making the point that double negatives in & of themselves aren't slang or informal. That's what I meant by word choice having an influence to whether it feels regional (e.g. "Ain't no", "Can't get no") or formal/standard (e.g. "not unheard of", "not uncommon").

Comment: Just to explicitly point it out: song lyrics tend to get a broader free pass here because of needing to conform to rhythm and/or rhyme, which can sometimes be achieved using the additional negative. While Bill Withers could've gotten away with "There's no sunshine when she's gone" while keeping the rhythm, the Rolling Stones couldn't easily have maintained the rhythm when avoiding the double negative in "I can't get no satisfaction".

Comment: Another example a little closer to the original phrase: "That just don't make no sense" is often used by southern/black Americans in movies like Forrest Gump or O Brother Where Art Thou, songs like YoungBoy Never Broke Again, or games like GTA V.

Comment: Additionally: in poetic usage, double-negatives like this can serve to emphasize the negation rather than negating it. "There's no sunshine when she's gone" has the same literal meaning as "ain't no sunshine...", but it lacks the latter's emotional punch - the former is clinically correct while the latter can be heart-wrenchingly visceral. OP's example also sets the tone for the show: informal, slang-ey language with "rule of cool" winning over many other considerations. The technodrome makes zero sense, but it's cool so it's in.

Comment: @anotherdave, I think the point is that usage of double-negative to _mean_ what the grammar says is perfectly standard.  To use a double-negative to mean the _opposite_ of what the grammar says (as per the examples in this answer) are non-standard.

Comment: The Pink Floyd example has inspired a meme that “You used a double negative, so obviously you *do* need education.”

Comment: @BillyKerr Double negatives are totally common in standard English. For example, "I *haven't* eaten *any* fries today." Here, "any" is used as a negative. (And if you insist that "any" is not a negative here, then why is "no" a negative in "I haven't eaten no fries today."? The rule isn't that a word is a negative if it starts with "n".)

Comment: @dan04 and anybody who says that (Moss included) is the one in need of an education - beginning with learning the definition of the word 'descriptivist' and following with the distinction between language and mathematics.

Comment: @DavidSvhwarts - never said they weren't common, or that there are no double negatives in standard English. But the kind of double negative in the OP's question isn't standard English. Some double negatives are allowed but not the kind shown here.